# title not showing up as tooltip on SVG path

Tags: jquery, html, svg, path

I have included 'title' tag as a child and 'pointer-events:all' to path but still it is not working.If I group path into 'g' it works. But i don't want to include them in 'g' as too many functions will be affected.Can someone please explain why this is happening? and what can i do about it?

```html
<div class="svg-container">
    <svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink">; 
        <path id="SvgjsPath5016" d="M582 128Q582 128 580 128Q578 128 555.5 131.5Q533 135 525 136.5Q517 138 498 144Q479 150 466.5 153.5Q454 157 444.5 158Q435 159 428.5 160.5Q422 162 414 163.5Q406 165 403 165Q400 165 398.5 166Q397 167 395.5 167Q394 167 392.5 167Q391 167 390.5 167Q390 167 389.5 167Q389 167 388 166Q387 165 387 163.5 " fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#7bd148" stroke-width="4">
            <title>Hello</title>
        </path> 
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: i have almost 25-30 paths.

Comment: @AlexeyGorozhanov - inlcluded the code. Please help.

Comment: If I run the code snippet and put the mouse over the line I see the hello tooltip. Is this not what you see? If not, what UA (browser) are you using?

Comment: I also get a title tooltip, tested in latest Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am not able to see the tooltip. i am using chrome.
Is it because of the version of chrome or anything else?

Comment: I tried with Chrome on my Mac and I can see the tooltip. I used Chrome 43.0.2357.81 Maybe try disabling extensions via chrome://extensions/

Comment: @RobertLongson disabled all the extensions but still no luck :(

Comment: If i run snippet here i can see the tooltip but not working in my application

Comment: So it's something in your application then. If you can't post a testcase that shows the issue we probably can't help.